# Specifying additional headers for each part of multipart request in Postman

Tags: java, file-upload, postman, content-length, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm implementing multi-part file upload with the following library:
[Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Since the files may be too large, I don't load the entire file to the the memory, I just do the job on the bytes as fast as they arrive. The problem that I have met is that I need the full size of the file to continue my processing. As the easiest solution I think about asking Front-End to send *Content-Length* headers for each part of multi-part request.

However, during the implementation, I need to be able to test that as well, and the problem here is that using Postman, I don't think that it provides default features to setup additional headers to multi-part request parts.

For now I use: *Body->form-data->key-type = file.*

The question is there a way to specify additional headers in Postman for different parts of the request? Hardcoding this data in the code is not that dynamic even for testing.